# php get 1st value of an array (associative or not)

Tags: php, arrays

This might sounds like a silly question. How do I get the 1st value of an array without knowing in advance if the array is associative or not?

In order to get the 1st element of an array I thought to do this:

```
function Get1stArrayValue($arr) { return current($arr); }
```

is it ok?
Could it create issues if array internal pointer was moved before function call?
Is there a better/smarter/fatser way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how you define a "first" element in an associative array ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better idea may be to use [reset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) which "rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element"

Example:

```
function Get1stArrayValue($arr) { return reset($arr); }
```

As [@therefromhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere) pointed out in the comment below, this solution is not ideal as it changes the state of the internal pointer. However, I don't think it is much of an issue as other functions such as [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) also reset it.
The main concern that it couldn't be used when iterating over an array isn't an problem as `foreach` operates on a copy of the array. The PHP manual states:

> Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself.

This can be shown using some simple test code:

```
$arr = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
foreach ( $arr as $val ){
    echo reset($arr) . " - " . $val . "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
a - a
a - b
a - c
a - d
```

Comment: Worth noting that since it rewinds the internal pointer then you shouldn't do this if you're in the middle of iterating this array.

Comment: Great Yacoby, therefor internal pointer is not affected by foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element for any array, you need to reset the pointer first.
https://www.php.net/reset

```
function Get1stArrayValue($arr) { 
  return reset($arr); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing the first element from the array, you can also use

[`array_shift()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) *- shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array  by one element and moving everything down. All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero while literal keys won't be touched.*

Or you could wrap the array into an ArrayIterator and use [`seek`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/seekableiterator.seek.php):

```
$array = array("foo" => "apple", "banana", "cherry", "damson", "elderberry");
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($array);
$iterator->seek(0);
echo $iterator->current(); // apple
```

If this is not an option either, use one of the other suggestions.