# PHP - write to first element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to write to the first element of an array?

I know reset can return the first element... but you can not use it to write to it.

Comment: sorry I was not clear... the array is not numeric... e.g $test['element_1']

Comment: Same questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230154/php-get-1st-value-of-an-array-associative-or-not/2230266 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236720/php-how-do-i-search-in-an-unindexed-array/2236732

Comment: The first question is similar... but its about accessing an array and not writing to it... the second is a completely different question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything wrong with `$yourarray[0] = $value` ?

If you don't want to overwrite the first element, try "array_unshift":

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

EDIT:
ok, use this for non-numerical keys:

```
reset($yourarray);
$key = key($yourarray);
$yourarray[$key] = $newvalue;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's called an "associative array" or a "hash". Technically, it doesn't have an order. You may have an item that you've put in first, but that's only incidental.

Comment: If it doesn't have an order, then why are there functions to sort it?

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
reset($x);
$x[0] = $value;
```

Comment: The reset isn't actually needed to set the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean prepend the array with a value?

[`array_unshift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) - this is costly, rebuilding the array.